# Free PXE boot server for Windows or OS X

Tags: windows, mac-osx, pxe-boot

OS X (leopard, not server) seems to have tftp and some kind of dhcp server built-in, which seems like it would be enough to make PXE boots happen, but I don't really know where to start. I have Windows (XP and 7) workstations available too.

I would prefer quick and dirty solutions to robust ones, since this is merely a temporary measure until I get my debian server running again. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, to build PXE-boot environment at home, i used:

- [Small HTTP server](http://smallsrv.com/) as DHCP-server
- [Tftpd32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) for TFTP-server

It seems Tftpd32 includes DHCP-server as well, and i dont remember correctly exactly why i used Small HTTP server instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Arch linux on a desktop computer via my macOS laptop. It's a bit involved, but you can do it using macOS's bootpd (combined BOOTP and DHCP) and tftp servers.

First download an [iPXE](http://ipxe.org/) netboot image for your distro, in my case ipxe.pxe in [arch releases](https://www.archlinux.org/releng/netboot/):

```
wget https://www.archlinux.org/static/netboot/ipxe.8da38b4a9310.pxe
```

Now connect your macOS system to client computer you wish to PXE boot install. I used an ethernet cable from my thunderbolt port, which left my laptop's WiFi connected to the internet.

Next set a manual IP address on your macOS -> client interface. Select your interface in network preferences and specify a manual IP address `192.168.2.254` and if needed use the subnet `255.255.255.0`.

At this stage, I enabled *Internet Sharing* in *System Preferences*, which creates a bridged adapter between the WiFi and ethernet. It's important that the client computer is connected already, otherwise the `/etc/bootpd.plist` configuration file will not be created correctly.

Now copy your netboot image to the tftp server root directory. By default this a directory owned by root with full read privileges at `/private/tftpboot`. Copy your netboot image into that directory:

```
sudo cp ipxe.8da38b4a9310.pxe /private/tftpboot
```

Next you must modify the bootpd server config file to point to your netboot image and tftp server. First you need to encode the filename of your netboot image as base64, which can be done as follows:

```
printf %s00 `echo -n ipxe.8da38b4a9310.pxe | xxd -p` | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
```

Now open your bootpd server configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/bootpd.plist
```

and add your static IP and the base64 encoded file name to the bottom of the `<subnet> <array> <dict>`:

```
<key>dhcp_option_66</key>
<string>192.168.2.254</string>
<key>dhcp_option_67</key>
<data>aXB4ZS44ZGEzOGI0YTkzMTAucHhlAA==</data>
```

My `bootpd.plist` now looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Subnets</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>_creator</key>
            <string>com.apple.NetworkSharing</string>
            <key>allocate</key>
            <true/>
            <key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
            <array>
                <string>192.168.2.1</string>
            </array>
            <key>dhcp_router</key>
            <string>192.168.2.1</string>
            <key>interface</key>
            <string>bridge100</string>
            <key>lease_max</key>
            <integer>86400</integer>
            <key>lease_min</key>
            <integer>86400</integer>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>192.168.2/24</string>
            <key>net_address</key>
            <string>192.168.2.0</string>
            <key>net_mask</key>
            <string>255.255.255.0</string>
            <key>net_range</key>
            <array>
                <string>192.168.2.2</string>
                <string>192.168.2.254</string>
            </array>
            <key>dhcp_option_66</key>
            <string>192.168.2.254</string>
            <key>dhcp_option_67</key>
            <data>aXB4ZS44ZGEzOGI0YTkzMTAucHhlAA==</data>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>bootp_enabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>detect_other_dhcp_server</key>
    <array>
        <string>bridge100</string>
    </array>
    <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
    <array>
        <string>bridge100</string>
    </array>
    <key>dhcp_ignore_client_identifier</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ignore_allow_deny</key>
    <array>
        <string>bridge100</string>
    </array>
    <key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now restart/enable the macOS bootpd and tftp server's by running:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/{bootps,tftp}.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/{bootps,tftp}.plist
```

Now you should test your tftp server by connecting locally and downloading your netboot image:

```
tftp localhost
tftp> get ipxe.8da38b4a9310.pxe
Received 343580 bytes in 0.1 seconds
tftp> quit
```

Now boot your client system with PXE enabled and it should find your macOS DHCP server (through bootpd), assign an IP address, find the TFTP server, transfer and run the netboot image! Success!

To disable the bootpd and tftp servers after you are done:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/{bootps,tftp}.plist
```